# AWS not building react-scripts with Node 12.x

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services

This build was working yesterday. Today, it's failing and there seems to be this error message stating a requirement of node 14 or greater. Does anybody know if AWS is refusing to build applications using node 12 or lower now?

[image]

Comment: That error is from NPM. AWS has nothing to do with it. Someone at some part of your dependency chain must have changed an engine requirement. The error mentions the package "serve@14" so that's a good place to start checking.

Comment: Thanks for the comment — it's much appreciated — I'll take a little look into the failing packages in which case. I thought there was a chance I was barking up the wrong tree!